# FackItEasy: How to get access to the value of a parameter passed to a faked interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I would like to check a property of a structure passed to a faked interface:

```
JobSpec passedJobSpec = null;
A.CallTo(() => fakeInvoker.Create(A<JobSpec>._))
            .Invokes((JobSpec jobSpec) => passedJobSpec = jobSpec);
Assert.NotNull(passedJobSpec.Property1);
```

But I get a `NullReferenceException` on accessing `passedJobSpec.Property1`.
I tried a few other variations but no luck so far. Appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 2):

`A.CallTo` will mock the behaviour for `fakeInvoker.Create`, but a call to `fakeInvoker.Create` still needs to be made.

Given that we have the following definitions below:

```
public interface IInvoker
{
    void Create(JobSpec jobSpec);
}

public class JobSpec
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Our test case would look something like:

```
var fakeInvoker = A.Fake<IInvoker>();
JobSpec passedJobSpec = null;
A.CallTo(() => fakeInvoker.Create(A<JobSpec>._))
    .Invokes((JobSpec jobSpec) => passedJobSpec = jobSpec);

// Make this call to fire off the behaviour
fakeInvoker.Create(new JobSpec{Property1 = "Hello world"});

Assert.NotNull(passedJobSpec.Property1);
```

Comment: I had that call as part of the logic I was testing, but I realized my test doesn't get there because of a minor test setup issue somewhere else. So, yes, this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some other good examples are provided here: https://www.alexjamesbrown.com/blog/development/asserting-multiple-properties-argument-fakeiteasy/

```
var fakeInvoker = A.Fake<IInvoker>();
JobSpec passedJobSpec = null;
    .Invokes(p => passedJobSpec = p.GetArgument<JobSpec>(0));
```

This is especially useful when the interface has multiple arguments.